# Do I need an article for these items?

Tags: articles, american-english, formal-language, ielts

I'm writing an ielts writing task 1 essay. It's about the expenditure in Million Pounds on fast food items by income groups in the UK and I have 3 items which are `hamburger`, `fish&chips` and `pizza`. Do I need an article for these items?

For example :

> More than 40 million pounds spent for hamburger by people who had high
>   income.

Comment: A few sample sentences might help...

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need articles, since you are using them as categories (collective nouns) and not describing a particular item, but you might want to use plurals

> million**s** of pound**s**
>   hamburger**s**
>   pizza**s**

Comment: With an explanation as short as this, OP might conclude that they should also use "fishes and chips".

Comment: Except "fishes and chips" is not the plural, just as "bacons and eggs" would be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

To take them one by one:

Hamburger is normally used as a countable noun (a hamburger, 2 hamburgers). You should normally talk how many *hamburgers* were eaten, using the plural.

Fish & chips is syntactically plural, but is often treated as a non-count noun. So you can say "Fish and chips (is/are) popular in the uk." And write about how much fish and chips was eaten. You can also use a counter: "How many servings of fish and chips..."

Pizza as a countable noun refers to a whole pie. It can also be used as a non-count noun, referring to a type of food. You can use both "How much was spent on (pizza/pizzas) ..." but in this use I'd prefer the non-count, singular.

There aren't many rules for this. The countability of nouns can't always be guessed, however, a quick glance at dictionary definitions of [hamburger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hamburger) and [pizza](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pizza#English) show the current usage for countability and plural formation.